# Facet graph : how to filter Y - array field

Tags: vega-lite, vega, deneb

As you can see here in the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-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-f414Ggjw6yHQ0Jwox2-1+1EkjHu3qekB4n0JwJ8wPpkM0+mM6MsuNszwesBJlOztPBoVZ0WZSXS2VbGyF7D4ZWnM917XPXUwn4ANjPJobFse1u-to39tHbxh1dTF-05LdcW9AlfX-f1dwFDNTQ8CpqjqZdmVjeNHXApMXlTBCZkPZZcxAdU5QvTBi1LctK1IatSIue8G11b4-nfdsHkfLtYT-FFAKHdEQNHHDIPxQlsLdfCg0FakQDpBlIyZGNWQTMJhjw+DpMQoixRPGVWwLPZrwrFU72uesOy4x4XzeF5HnYpDOPuL8f0tXikR6IDBN6UDsQgr0xJgvipPnIVQ1QiMQCjDCVIktShk+EL90zEViIyM9DMVYzaLMrUG2+azmwc5juJ7dyAM8gSXR84TE1EqcJJnUk9xkxz5PQ5S11UrdhkSzTQpS7NjylfSGPzCisoOEzb1bJjLIhKEPh3MbNg-eaXJtPtYIdbbnTAyS4rAZbJ2gyqSX5LSFxAFDww61csP2nx7h5JLWp0uSSLI88dkvGjTNm8yH2cq0Pj6la20cztFrKrbgsHPaR2646oPE7bzrnZLHJutDFJXTD1z857k1e7TUpzdKDImq8ppygG8vm3VoQNYqGdK3sETRyqEaEpH6tOwd0ZaxDwtu3GYq6w6iY05qCIPMmPop8HMupm9VXBuanN1H9pa+tbNbZ8qB124Cat5gKGs5-rMZFnGoqU+6Cc3ImwYugbhSGlZFa+5W-pm9XAZKx5fkhFtwb1qHu3Z-sdpRbnTcOw0JxRoKPKt1qbci6LOoevykzhNPSY9z6Lh97L-v9+n9cKuyWf16Go85+GTeJbrE5O1HEYLq72rF7PHbHHqhnzmXLrloaJRGjKqd9tWvo1zsmz1WvwQ238DAAXSMEBcnIAgHVABgAHcLG3tczkajADC38hbhwcQIAAL0vBQ1aIKadBPyACF9ZAAAsCkSHgOwoonjGDmJQUgWQn6IBhI8R4V9jDiDkKiE+h8ICkDAL-RAvw4HGF-rAbIv93AAE5HjGA0AAT1gMQRwoBKHUNoSABQxByBHFFE4EAeBWGXh0MQdB6RxBdAEh4bQKBiDbHSAsPA58QDiEKHAewG9jBgBYXgcQuQSBHEYfkaAYiT75C6DI9uyRjD4FgFUXIjh9qBE3kokARxFA-3ABQ5BmBwE0NMQoAgUAKGIFCMYIgxAgHEAaOQUgEAmCilCGQ0+0BoBVC8T4xAjwAB0MI8EEJ0EQvxMIr7r2MO0Ig4TdAn1QPos+mA54B2US4y8KAjhyBIKIdI5BUDZmQFAOAiA8BMDicYXh-CEAqNsOQ8gcwujlFQHIGhHgHCQBOECTRRQAAUpgmBHBSQWAQAByAApHMbZABKAQ8zYCLOOCstZGytnUD2UcI51AAC8jzbmPFCNs6gAB+agpzzkOLAKsoo6zNkXh2bsgAmg8hAtztnr3SAM0g6xxBYKQCAN+4SFzIDsO4UABjoAyMMsoiAJwACqWg7hHHwJg9IsAACOTBmkIFCFvTKDhN7GFZfcPg9x2XgAAUilFoB0VQDCqilA4gcWn0MZgQlfLSXkswJSjoWCCn0sZcyjlE02Usq1VynlV8t6oBTKivFMjdagi3r4k1FSPBZwdukMAtTMB4BwEcbQzTjCtPaXymAhYel9JAAixAwzYBEu-qUCBmA0AoA6IYA1HMVGUHUZoxh8iCC9I2M6nAh9lmHJaUeF1h9YimsMPk+xjjP5Oo8MQXp8AAk4GgCQTAABiIE5RfgvF+MQgRj9Cz+JADgRJjrkkpM+FvQpjBtAf1RWU610qPCFuLRUmpriPD1MaSw7o8bkCqOTccbREBdEMLnfizAxj0hmIsVY4Ktiy0OOIE4x1q6mE4FEekIgjaZkgGbeULAL4XzPB7dAplsDTF8JZJgX+JBH5Uo9QOodVrUm-EQb-cgz6VEQEoDoOAbwmByHhCACdxTp1CobU2k9ZqS4UUQfIwsB8sOFgcN+39-7APGFbUCUonw4EgFscYWduKbUV3rCuupsAGlNK3cYK1gn512zxipUTWa3VcK3XkrebRxANssHRkAXrRSgCtSAbQpBYDIOkRBg1QA), the version axis shows the version of all product, for each products.

On the exemple there is only 2 products, but I am working with an undefined numbers of products, and I donct want to hardcode a Vconcat for each one.

I would like to make Y axis independant between the different facet i.e. display Product1 according to version that he is using, and Product2 the same.  I've been trying for 5/10h+ but can't figure it out alone. Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

[image]

If so, set your scale to independent.

```
{
  "title": {
    "text": "Concordance Produit / Projet, réalisé à partir du planning "
  },
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Projet": "Project",
        "Produit": "Product1",
        "ID_task": "Projet",
        "Signification": "BESOIN",
        "Référentiel": "Product 1 V1 ",
        "Signification_bis": "MES",
        "Date_value": "Confirmed",
        "Date_Début": "2023-04-28",
        "Date_Fin": "2023-11-15"
      },
      {
        "Projet": "Project",
        "Produit": "Product1",
        "ID_task": "Produit",
        "Signification": "MAD",
        "Référentiel": "Product 1 V1 ",
        "Signification_bis": "START",
        "Date_value": "Confirmed",
        "Date_Début": "2023-03-31",
        "Date_Fin": "2022-07-07"
      },
      {
        "Projet": "Project",
        "Produit": "Product1",
        "ID_task": "Projet",
        "Signification": "BESOIN",
        "Référentiel": "Product1 V2",
        "Signification_bis": "MES",
        "Date_value": "ToBeConfirmed ",
        "Date_Début": "2023-04-28",
        "Date_Fin": "2023-11-15"
      },
      {
        "Projet": "Project",
        "Produit": "Product1",
        "ID_task": "Produit",
        "Signification": "MAD",
        "Référentiel": "Product1 V2",
        "Signification_bis": "START",
        "Date_value": "Confirmed",
        "Date_Début": "2023-05-26",
        "Date_Fin": "2022-07-07"
      },
      {
        "Projet": "Project",
        "Produit": "Product1",
        "ID_task": "Projet",
        "Signification": "BESOIN",
        "Référentiel": "Product1 V3",
        "Signification_bis": "MES",
        "Date_value": "ToBeConfirmed ",
        "Date_Début": "2023-04-28",
        "Date_Fin": "2023-11-15"
      },
      {
        "Projet": "Project",
        "Produit": "Product1",
        "ID_task": "Produit",
        "Signification": "MAD",
        "Référentiel": "Product1 V3",
        "Signification_bis": "START",
        "Date_value": "Confirmed",
        "Date_Début": "2023-06-30",
        "Date_Fin": "2022-07-07"
      },
      {
        "Projet": "Project",
        "Produit": "Product1",
        "ID_task": "Projet",
        "Signification": "BESOIN",
        "Référentiel": "Product1 V4",
        "Signification_bis": "MES",
        "Date_value": "Confirmed",
        "Date_Début": "2024-06-28",
        "Date_Fin": "2023-11-15"
      },
      {
        "Projet": "Project",
        "Produit": "Product1",
        "ID_task": "Produit",
        "Signification": "MAD",
        "Référentiel": "Product1 V4",
        "Signification_bis": "START",
        "Date_value": "Confirmed",
        "Date_Début": "2023-11-02",
        "Date_Fin": "2022-07-07"
      },
      {
        "Projet": "Project",
        "Produit": "Product2",
        "ID_task": "Projet",
        "Signification": "BESOIN",
        "Référentiel": "Product2 V1",
        "Signification_bis": "MES",
        "Date_value": "Confirmed",
        "Date_Début": "2022-07-04",
        "Date_Fin": "2023-11-15"
      },
      {
        "Projet": "Project",
        "Produit": "Product2",
        "ID_task": "Projet",
        "Signification": "BESOIN",
        "Référentiel": "Product2 V2",
        "Signification_bis": "MES",
        "Date_value": "Confirmed",
        "Date_Début": "2023-01-31",
        "Date_Fin": "2023-11-15"
      },
      {
        "Projet": "Project",
        "Produit": "Product2",
        "ID_task": "Projet",
        "Signification": "BESOIN",
        "Référentiel": "Product2 V3",
        "Signification_bis": "MES",
        "Date_value": "Confirmed",
        "Date_Début": "2023-07-03",
        "Date_Fin": "2023-11-15"
      },
      {
        "Projet": "Project",
        "Produit": "Product2",
        "ID_task": "Projet",
        "Signification": "BESOIN",
        "Référentiel": "Product2 V4",
        "Signification_bis": "MES",
        "Date_value": "Confirmed",
        "Date_Début": "2023-08-18",
        "Date_Fin": "2023-11-15"
      },
      {
        "Projet": "Project",
        "Produit": "Product1",
        "ID_task": "Projet",
        "Signification": "BESOIN",
        "Référentiel": "Product1 V5",
        "Signification_bis": "MES",
        "Date_value": "Confirmed",
        "Date_Début": "2023-06-30",
        "Date_Fin": "2023-11-15"
      },
      {
        "Projet": "Project",
        "Produit": "Product1",
        "ID_task": "Produit",
        "Signification": "MAD",
        "Référentiel": "Product1 V5",
        "Signification_bis": "START",
        "Date_value": "Confirmed",
        "Date_Début": "2023-04-03",
        "Date_Fin": "2022-07-07"
      }
    ]
  },
  "facet": {"row": {"field": "Produit"}},
  "autosize": "pad",
  "config": {"tick": {"thickness": 20, "bandSize": 500}},
  "spec": {
    "width": 800,
    "height": 90,
    "layer": [
      {
        "layer": [
          {
            "params": [
              {"name": "grid", "select": "interval", "bind": "scales"}
            ],
            "transform": [
              {"filter": {"field": "ID_task", "oneOf": ["Produit"]}}
            ],
            "mark": {
              "type": "bar",
              "opacity": 1,
              "cornerRadius": 10,
              "fillOpacity": 0.5,
              "height": 15
            }
          }
        ],
        "encoding": {
          "x": {
            "field": "Date_Début",
            "type": "temporal",
            "axis": {
              "title": null,
              "grid": true,
              "labelExpr": "[timeFormat(datum.value, '%b'), timeFormat(datum.value, '%m') == '01' ? timeFormat(datum.value, '%Y') : '']",
              "gridDash": {
                "condition": {
                  "test": {"field": "value", "timeUnit": "month", "equal": 1},
                  "value": []
                },
                "value": [2, 2]
              },
              "tickDash": {
                "condition": {
                  "test": {"field": "value", "timeUnit": "month", "equal": 1},
                  "value": []
                },
                "value": [2, 2]
              }
            }
          },
          "x2": {"field": "Date_Fin"},
          "y": {
            "field": "Référentiel",
            "type": "nominal",
            "axis": {"title": null, "grid": true, "tickBand": "extent"}
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "transform": [{"calculate": "now()", "as": "now_field"}],
        "mark": {"type": "rule", "color": "#FE8389", "size": 1, "opacity": 0.4},
        "encoding": {"x": {"field": "now_field", "type": "temporal"}}
      },
      {
        "transform": [{"filter": {"field": "ID_task", "oneOf": ["Projet"]}}],
        "mark": {
          "type": "point",
          "color": "#EC6602",
          "size": 150,
          "orient": "horizontal",
          "opacity": 0.8,
          "shape": "triangle-up"
        },
        "encoding": {
          "color": {
            "field": "Date_value",
            "scale": {"range": ["#EC6602", "#FFB400"]}
          },
          "x": {"field": "Date_Début", "type": "temporal"},
          "y": {"field": "Référentiel", "type": "nominal"}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent"}}
}
```